# "Referencing the Window in Angular expressions is disallowed!" occurs when not using window

Tags: angularjs

I recently moved from AngularJS **v1.2.17** to **v1.2.28** which is the latest stable build and I realized that one of my pages now throws a bunch of JS errors telling me the following:

> Error: [$parse:isecwindow] Referencing the Window in Angular
>   expressions is disallowed! Expression: model.skAccount.Phone

The thing is I have not touched this code in weeks so it makes no sense that it would not work.  After looking for some reference to `window` in the template or my controller I found nothing at all.

This is what the HTML looks like for this Expression:

```
<li>
     <label for="inputAccountPhone">Phone number</label>
     <input id="inputAccountPhone" type="text" sk-phone-number ng-model="model.skAccount.Phone" required/>
</li>
```

This is just a simple form and there is absolutely no reference to `window`.  I then reverted my AngularJS version back to 1.2.17 and everything works just fine. Does this sound like a bug with Angular?

**Requested skPhoneNumber directive**

```
app.directive('skPhoneNumber', function(){
    return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            phone: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.$watch('phone', function(newVal){
                if(newVal){
                    scope.phone = newVal.replace( /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '($1) $2-$3');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

After further testing, I found that the problem was introduced in **v1.2.19**

Comment: What is `sk-phone-number`? Can you show us the implementation for that directive?

Comment: yeah it is a very simple directive to run regex on the input and format the numbers into a phone number.. adding the directive now

Comment: Once again, i swear there is no reference to `window` I have done a full search for references across the entire module for this app and it is never used...

Comment: What I don't understand is why Angular is giving this error when my expression clearly does not involve Window

Comment: There must be some reason why it's taking issue with that particular expression, even if it is a bug. Can you reproduce the issue in plnkr? Maybe it's possible to trace the code in the debugger and see why it thinks that expression is referencing window.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not sure why the error was thrown on this particular expression since I have many expressions preceding this one, but I have found the problem.

In my controller I always use `$scope.model` for my view model and I typically initialize the model by doing something like

```
function HomeViewModel(){
    this.title = "Hello";
    this.content = "World!";
}

$scope.model = new HomeViewModel();
```

However I accidentally had only

```
$scope.model = HomeViewModel();
```

So I forgot my `new` operator.  Leaving out the `new` operator caused the `this` reference inside of my HomeViewModel class to become a reference to `window`. Therefore, instead of having:

```
$scope.model = {
    title: "Hello",
    content: "World!"
}
```

`$scope.model` was equal to `window` with `title` and `content` extended.  Because of this, the newer versions of Angular run a check to make sure the objects are NOT `window` objects and this caused that check to fail and the exception was thrown.

For some reason, prior to AngularJS **v1.2.19**, this check was never being done so my code has been just "working".